# Unable to pass JSONObject from Grails Controller to the Grails service

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Is something I am doing wrong here, I am unable to pass the **JSON Object** to the **Grails Service** from **Grails Controller**.

```
class SampleController {

  def sampleService

  def updateProduct() {
    def jq = request.JSON
    sampleService(jq)
  }    
}

class SampleService { 

  def updateProduct (JSONObject requestJSON) {
    if (!requestJSON) {
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

No signature of method: `com.SampleService.call()` is applicable for argument types: `(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject)` values:

Possible solutions:

`wait()`, `any()`, `wait(long)`, `any(groovy.lang.Closure)`, `each(groovy.lang.Closure`), `find()`.

Stacktrace follows:

Comment: Would you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Error 2013-03-01 10:15:45,056 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request:
No signature of method: com.SampleService.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject) values: Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), any(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), find(). Stacktrace follows:

Comment: I guess `sampleService(jq)` should be `sampleService.updateProduct(jq)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call the service object as a method.

`sampleService(jq)` should be `sampleService.updateProduct(jq)`

Comment: Omg how did I miss this thing :) silly mistake Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Now its working.